# How to plot the outlines of specific squares within a 2D grid using pcolormesh?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a (21 x 25) 2D array which contains two discrete values, "1" & "2". 
The values are shown below:

```
value = np.array(
    [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
       1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

If I plot this using `pcolor`, the resulting figure looks like this:

[image]

I want to draw the outlines of the grid squares where `value == 2`:

```
xx,yy = np.linspace(0,26,25),np.linspace(0,22,22)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(xx,yy)
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, value, facecolor='none', edgecolor='b', alpha=0.8, zorder=2)
```

[image]

It seems like the outline isn't uniform (the lines have different shades), and I can't set the grid line colors by changing `edgecolor`.

Comment: I assume that `impact == value`?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to change the array name. 'impact' & 'value' are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render the squares where `value == 1` as transparent by creating an `np.ma.masked_array` from `value`:

```
c = np.ma.masked_array(value, value == 1.)  # mask squares where value == 1
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, c, alpha=0.8, zorder=2, facecolor='none', edgecolors='k',
               cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Setting the colormap to `'gray'` is a bit of a hack - unfortunately it seems that the default colormap overrides the edge color, even if you try to set it explicitly using `edgecolor=` or `edgecolors=`. I'm not sure whether or not this should be considered a bug in matplotlib.